# What is the green/red line in this analysis

Tags: analysis

I ran a game of mine on:

http://analysis.cpuchess.com/

And I see that the analysis line changes from green to red and vice versa. What does it mean? Do the green lines mark the move was the engine's choice and red not? Does it make sense in the attached picture for 1400 and 1600 players?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems obvious to me that a red line indicates a bad move and a green line a good move. Graphically this shows in the fact that steep lines are red and horizontal lines are green. This might be slightly confusing because the graph shows the moves of both, black and white.

Because an engine always assumes best play when evaluating a position you can never improve your position by playing a move, best case scenario is you play the best move and the eval stays the same -> horizontal line. A mistake on the other hand changes the evaluation -> the line goes up if black moved, or down if white moved.

There is probably a cutoff for what constitutes a bad move, something like a 1.0 pawns evaluation drop seems likely.

Comment: So, if I run the engine and ask it to play as black, the green line means that the move was only good for black? Or good in general? Meaning - if white moved and did a good move according to white's perceptive, will the line be red or green?

Comment: This graph will always look the same whether you are playing black or white. There is a little line for every move, by black and by white. White's moves that are good for white will be green. Black's moves that are good for black will also be green.

Answer (score 0):

"Green" means advantage, and "red" means disadvantage for you.

Basically, you had a slight advantage for most of the game, then made a terrible move or two at the end that lost you the game.

Comment: I'm not sure that's correct. I played black and it seems like the analysis favors black, but still appears red.

Comment: @Avi: Maybe the analysis was from White's point of view, you were at a slight disadvantage as black until you won.